# How to understand multi-threading and mutual exclusion primitives

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, locking, semaphore

I am currently learning multithreading and the use of mutual exclusion structures such as locks, semaphores, and conditional variables.

When would be the best time to use each of the 3 mutual exclusions，and are there any real life examples that use these structures?

Any hint would be helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. You are better off reading a textbook or reading the wikipedia for each of those primitives to understand when they'd be needed/appropriate.

Comment: my favorite `pthreads` tutorial. Even if you're not using `pthreads` the concepts are the same: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they have varying levels of sophistication and performance. To begin with, I point out that there are variations on all these locking methods and I have to make assumptions as to what variant you are referring to.

1. Lock managers tend to be the most sophisticated. A decent lock manager is capable of detecting and breaking deadlocks. Lock managers are typically used to synchronize database accesses. There are a lot of variations in lock manager capabilities.
2. Semaphores also have a number of variants. They can be set up to handle single accesses, multiple accesses, single/multiple access (e.g., 1 writer or multiple readers). The level of overhead is much less than with a lock manager. However, applications have to handle deadlocks on their own.
3. Condition variables tend to be the simplest method of locking. Invariably they rely on hardware instructions designed for locking, such as a Test and Set Interlocked instruction. This is often used for spin locks used for kernel resources.